# How to install/start using DOM for Eclipse?

Tags: xml, eclipse, dom, plugins

I can't seem to find a good tutorial on how to install and start using DOM for Eclipse. Could someone please point me in the right direction or redirect me to a tutorial?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing eclipse-specific to be aware of in order to start with DOM.

All the  [necessary classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/package-summary.html)  are already delivered with the JDK. Just create a new java project and you're ready to go.

You can try [this sun tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPIntro.html) to get you started. I cannot provide the link to the right page, but it's the chapter 6.

Comment: Thank you! You're right, just tried using it and it recognised all the imports etc.